# Apply linear gradient to background

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to apply linear gradient to the background, but there are stripes that appear in the middle I'm not getting a smooth gradient, how to get a smooth gradient from top to bottom

MY CSS

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background: #DADADA;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, #DADADA);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(white, #DADADA);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(white, #DADADA);
background: -o-linear-gradient(white, #DADADA);
```

My Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/3njyc0xm/

Comment: Yes, I think there is a problem with "your" colors. I have tried your code with other colors, and there is no problem. https://jsfiddle.net/3njyc0xm/2/
So, maybe it is an optical illusion.

Comment: it works good, just your difference of colors are not verry important... but it works. You can check in a little container : https://jsfiddle.net/3njyc0xm/3/

Comment: actually, there are stripes it is just too small @al

Comment: actually, there are stripes it is just too small @Alexis

Comment: It works with all browser for me.

Comment: It works in all browser except chrome, May be a browser bug.

Comment: @Everyone Anyway it was a very interesting problem. We decoded the answer together, but unfortunately we could't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think there is a problem with "your" colors. I have tried your code with other colors, and there is no problem.

I have tried your jsfiddle gradient in Firefox and Edge, and it seems that there is no problem with your colors, so maybe there is a Chrome bug, or something.

Comment: ok, I am very curios, because this is an interesting problem.

Comment: Actually Gehnet is correct , he answered below, it works in firefox but in chrome it causes problem

Comment: I have tried to move my laptop screen up and down, and I observed that only in specific views are problems with your gradient in Chrome. Maybe Chrome doesn't handle perfectly the gradients, and with some specific colors and specific screen views will occur this gradient problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox your example works fine, but I think the "normal" CSS property is needed for some browsers. Just add it with

```
background: linear-gradient(white, #DADADA);
```

I edited your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0gf52p68/)

Comment: I have tried your jsfiddle, and the problem still persists in my Chrome.

Comment: yeah , browser bug.@KicsiViziló